# Is there any way to select option when user clicks on dropdown and on refresh same selected option must be displayed in html/javascript/reactj.s?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

import React,{useState} from 'react'
import Api from '../../api/api'

const Select = ({data}) => {
const [opt,setOpt]=useState('')

```
const handleChange=(e)=>{
    
    setOpt(e.target.value)
 
}
return (
    <>
        <select onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}>
           {data.map(i=><>
            <option selected={opt==i.id} value={i.id}>{i.name}</option>
           </>)}
        </select>
    </>
)
```

}
export default Select

Comment: use browser [Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage)

Comment: https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage

Comment: in localStorage i can store value selected of one selected value but its a table with select dropdown for each row...so how to display selected option for each row if user selects any option of suppose if for 3rd row user have selected option 2 we can display that from localStorage but for 5th row if user selects option 1 then in localStorage selected 3rd row option would change from 2option to 1option

Comment: You can store a stringified array/object in `localStorage` that would keep track of the selected options for each row.